# Тире после слова «ты»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли ставить тире в подобном предложении:

*С чего вдруг ты (–) и с ней?*

Ведь получается, что сказуемое (встречаешься) пропущено?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос и за оценку ответа!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***С чего вдруг ты — и с ней?***

Тире в подобного рода разговорных фразах призвано отражать интонацию (паузу, логическое выделение отдельных слов).

[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#) (Розенталь)

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): <...>
>    *И это вы — при дочери?* (Фед.)...

Такое тире можно назвать [**интонационным**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94).

> 1. Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен.